# Copy string to model (Swift 3)

Tags: arrays, swift

My PhotoModel is returning nothing for eventDate()..

I have set it with

```
let newPhotos = PhotosModel()  // Create the instance
newPhotos.eventDate = item.event_date!  // Set the parameter
```

inside didSelectItemAt which when printed returns the correct date in the previous viewcontroller but isn't pushing it to the PhotoModel string.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or demonstrate what needs to be done that would be great, thank you.

ViewController:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    
    // Configure the cell
    let item: CoverModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! CoverModel
    
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailCollectionViewController") as! DetailCollectionViewController
    
    print(item.event_date!)
    
    let newPhotos = PhotosModel()  // Create the instance
    newPhotos.eventDate = item.event_date!  // Set the parameter
    
    print(newPhotos.eventDate)
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
}
```

PhotosModel:

```
protocol PhotosProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}

class PhotosModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    //properties
    weak var delegate: PhotosProtocol!
    
    var eventDate = String()
    var data = Data()
    
    func downloadItems() {
        let urlPath: String = "http://www.britanniaclub.co.uk/app_calls/britalbum.php?eventdate=\(eventDate)"
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        print("the event date is \(eventDate)")
        print("the urlPath is \(urlPath)")
        
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Event Data downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Output is:

> 2017-07-14
>
> the event date is
>
> the urlPath is http://www.britanniaclub.co.uk/app_calls/britalbum.php?eventdate=

Event Data downloaded

Comment: You never do anything with `newPhotos` other than set the `eventDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are not assigning `newPhotos` to any property of `DetailCollectionViewController`. You will have to do it before pushing this view controller.